# Is time diversification effective?

Tags: risk, diversification

[image]

If the returns are log-normal, how do I find the probability of negative returns, since log can only take positive values as an argument. Also, for time = more than 1 year, how do I find the probabilities?

Comment: They are considering the *Gross Return* $P_1/P_0$ to be lognormal (not the net return). The log of this is normally distributed, so that the mean of $\ln(P_1/P_0)$ is $\ln(1.1)$ = 0.095. And the standard deviation is $\ln(1.2)$ = 0.182. So the normal random variable is in [0.46,-0.27] 95% of the time. When this rv is <0 you have a loss for the year i.e. $P_1<P_0$.

Comment: For the two year case consider that $\ln(P_2/P_0)=\ln(P_2/P_1)+\ln(P_1/P_0)$ and apply properties of the sum of two independent normal rvs.